# Azure Digital Twin Authentication - InteractiveBrowserCredential Authentication Failed

Tags: azure, azure-digital-twins

Trying to run the sample from [Azure-Samples/digital-twins-samples](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/digital-twins-samples).
It is failing here in this code
`client.GetDigitalTwin("---");`

I have entered the required credentials in the authentication window and it gives an exception saying "InteractiveBrowserCredential Authentication Failed".

Inner Exception - "Only loopback redirect uri is supported, but urn:iet:wg:oauth:2.0:oob was found." Configure http://localhost or http://localhost:port both during app registration and when you create the PublicClientApplication object. See https://aka.ms/msal-net-os-browser for details

I have verified whether the role "Azure Digital Twins Owner (Preview)" is present for my user id and I am able to view/update the models & twins in the digital explorer sample from this example [ADT explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/digital-twins-explorer/digital-twins-explorer/), but unable to update model through code. I believe there is some configuration missing in the reply url of the desktop/web url.

Any idea how to fix this issue.

Comment: What is the complete Redirect URL you gave when registering the APP in AAD? Have you enabled the Tokens as well?

Comment: I have provided Web url as "http://localhost", please suggest any other url to be added. Access Tokens & ID Tokens are enabled.

Comment: May I know from which document you have taken that instruction ? have you tried http://localhost:3000 ? I have created a new user like 'Tester@satishOrg.onmicrosoft.com' and used that for the login , also provided the ADT Owner Permissions to this user.

Comment: I tried with multiple options. Initially with http://localhost:3000 and then http://localhost. I have created the twin using scripted version as provided in this document "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/digital-twins/how-to-set-up-instance-scripted". Both gives same error.

Comment: Ok, please remove the tokens and keep only 'Mobile & Desktop' AAD App Authentication, and try again.

Comment: I removed web authentication and added 'mobile & desktop' with redirect url as "http://localhost:3000" and this has not resolved the issue. Do we need to add any urls related to msal? please confirm and thanks for trying to resolve the issue.

Comment: have you selected the checkbox which says (MSAL only) when you have added 'Mobile & Desktop App' Platform?

Comment: Sorry many questions, i hope you have provided the values for "tenantId":   "clientId":   'instanceUrl' inside the ServiceConfig.json file ? and plz remove ur latest comment to avoid sensitive data on the public forums.

Comment: yes, I provided the details in serviceConfig.json, updated the properties to "Copy if newer" and verified in the code whether the values are getting assigned.

Comment: Please send an email to azcommunity@microsoft.com with these details,Thread URL: Link to this thread.
Azure Subscription ID: 
Email Subject : Attn Satish Boddu 
We will work on this with you!

Comment: I sent email to azcommunity@microsoft.com with the details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After discussing directly on this issue, we observed that the Internet Explorer on Client Machine is causing/experiencing some blocking on pop-ups.

**Resolution 1:**

- Please check if there are any pop-up blockers enabled on the browser.
- Please change the default browser to another browser [like chrome]
  and re-try.
- Clear the browser cache and close all opened browser sessions.
- Restart VS2019 and try to run the sample code.

**Resolution 2:**

- Make sure you are using **Azure.Identity** latest NuGet Package. As of today 09/02/2020 the working version is Azure.Identity 1.2.2

**Resolution 3:**

Please make sure the AAD Application Authentication has a 'Mobile & Desktop Application' Platform added, along with the redirect URL.
For more information please visit this [Github issue:](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/60633#issuecomment-680209708)