# How to create AzureProfile.json file using AzModule command in PowerShell?

Tags: azure, powershell, powershell-5.0, powershell-az-module

I want to create the AzureProfile.json file using the Az Module command in PowerShell, so that I can import the json file anytime I want to login to Azure to start\stop my VM's.

Below is the command\script I am using to create it but it is giving me error as shown in the screenshot.

[image]

I tried using the below code as well but it gives same error.

```
Connect-AzAccount -UseDeviceAuthentication

Save-AzProfile -path "$PSScriptRoot\AzureProfile.json"
```

> WARNING: Unable to acquire token for tenant 'organizations'
> Connect-AzAccount : DeviceCodeCredential authentication failed: Retry
> failed after 4 tries.

Answer (score 1):

*From the error message, it looks like the authentication of your account is failing in the Browser pop-up that comes after `Login-AzAccount`.*

I ran the **first set of commands** and it ran successfully.

**Powershell:**

[image]

**Created File:**

[image]

Note that my **PowerShell version** is `5.7.0.18831`.

Comment: I tried the same it gives me error my PS version is 5.1                                                                                                                                     WARNING: Unable to acquire token for tenant 'organizations'
Connect-AzAccount : An error occurred while sending the request.
At line:1 char:1
+ Connect-AzAccount
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Connect-AzAccount], HttpRequestException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.ConnectAzureRmAccountCommand

Comment: Did authentication succeed in the browser? Also, try running these commands in 'Powershell' instead of 'Powershell ISE'.

Comment: Check out this issue once: https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/13340

Comment: The above command I executed in PowerShell like you, after entering that command a popup windows appeared which asked me to enter the username and after clicking on Next it asked me to enter the password and after entering the password and i clicked on sign in and then i gave me the error in PowerShell.

Comment: Also, try performing steps mentioned in this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63295518/azure-digital-twin-authentication-interactivebrowsercredential-authentication by SatishBoddu

Comment: I think it can be related to your browser: it can be blocking pop- ups/cache is there. Pls check above issue once and try the browser steps only.

Comment: Tried it, same error, cleared cache and enabled pop-ups from browser settings, restarted the browser..still throws the same error as shown in above comment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227524/discussion-between-singhh-msft-and-srp).

Answer (score 1):

You have tried both :

- Connect-AzAccount -UseDeviceAuthentication
- Login-AzAccount

Both Interactive and non-interactive mode of login.

The error is occurring while trying you communicate to azure. I am suspecting it could be an issue at a machine level or network level (proxy/firewall)

[image]

The above issue usually occurs (reproducible at my end) when there are connection issues with the Microsoft Services - blocked by proxy /firewall/GPO etc...

For a quick test you could run the below PowerShell command :

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/devicecode" -Body "client_id=1950a258-227b-4e31-a9cf-717495945fc2&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fmanagement.core.windows.net%2F%2F.default+offline_access+profile+openid" -Method Post
```

**Sample Success Response :**

[image]

**Why the above command ?**

The above end point `https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/devicecode` is hit when you use `Connect-AzAccount -UseDeviceAuthentication` by powershell.

[image]

If you encounter a timeout/Name unresolvable issue - the issue is with the network/machine config.

Comment: Did you get the code for the -UseDeviceAuthentication ?

Comment: Yes, i received the same success response like you after triggering the command provided by you.

Comment: How about when you run `Connect-AzAccount -UseDeviceAuthentication`

Comment: Yes, when tried with PowerShell by entering "Connect-AzAccount -UseDeviceAuthentication" command after entering the command on browser it says "You have signed in to the Microsoft Azure PowerShell application on your device. You may now close this window."  and on PowerShell prompt it gives error "WARNING: Unable to acquire token for tenant 'organizations'
Connect-AzAccount : An error occurred while sending the request.
At line:1 char:1
+ Connect-AzAccount -UseDeviceAuthentication"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Comment: The query needs a further information & probing. Please send mail to AzCommunity [at] microsoft dot com with subject: "ATTN: Sathya" and a link to this forum thread (for context).